# Given a set and a pairwise xor set, find the second set?

Tags: algorithm

We take 2 sets of integers to generate a third set with contains the xor of every element in the first set with every element in the second set.

Now as a problem we have been given the first set and the third set i.e. the set with xors, and we need to generate the second set.

**It is guaranteed that there is only one possible answer for the inputs**

For Example:

(using binary here for clarity)

**Inputs:**

**Set1:** {101, 111}

**Set3:** {001, 011}

then **Set2**, the solution set will be

**Set2:** {110, 100}

as, if we do *Set1 ^ Set2*

{011, 001, 001, 011}

**Important Points:**

- the inputs are sets, not arrays, so no repetitions
- that doesn't mean that there weren't repetitions when set3 was created, a^d may be equal to b^c
- there is no size constraint that set1 and set2 have to be of same size.

Also, my test case isn't that great as in this it looks like we can simply do set1^set3 to get the answer, but that is clearly not the correct way.

Comment: XOR is a one-to-one mapping if you divide it into halves based on one of the inputs. Just encode the mapping in a dictionary and iterate over the pairs.

Comment: can you elaborate the divide it into halves part

Comment: You can't, at least not uniquely: first = {0b00, 0b01} and third = {0b00, 0b01, 0b10, 0b11} could be second = {0b00, 0b10} or second = {0b00, 0b11}.

Comment: sorry about that, I have updated the problem statement

Comment: @suyash consider the first element in all sets WLOG. if set 1 has a bit 0 at position 0, then mapping {0: 0, 1:1} can be applied to position 0 of set 3. else set 1 has bit 1 at position 0, therefore mapping {0:1, 1:0} can be applied to position 0 of set 3.

Comment: @suyash asking homework assignment is fine. next time please provide with what you have tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: (1). set1 is a set of elements, how can you create a map assuming all numbers to have bit 0/1 at position 0     (2). also set3 might not have m x n elements, read the updated problem statement     (3). This is an interview question, not homework

Comment: @suyash consider the first element in all sets without lost of generality. You are now comparing two bit-strings.

Comment: @suyash OK, I see what you mean now...Start now with dynamic programming to try all bit string with 3 bits (or n bits), only 8 possibilities. Group them into a set, that's maximal set 2, though any subset that covers set 2 with xor(set1) is fine. (Note bits are independent in xor, imagine you are marking allowed bit values at each position, and generate allowed elements in set2).

Answer (score -1):

if you have set1 = (a, b) and set2 = (c, d)
Then you are provided with set3 = (a^c, a^d, b^c, b^d) and need to to find set2.

So we know that first element in set 3 is a^c, so to find c, we will do (a^c)^a => c
Then to find d, we will pick b^d from set3 and (b^d)^b(from set1) and we will get d.

Comment: We have sets as input, if set1 is given as {a, b} and set2 is given as {c, d}, then the xor set is {a^c, a^d, b^c, b^d}, doing set1 ^ set3 gives {c, d, a^b^c, a^b^d}

Comment: how do you know which one is a^c and which one is b^d, given we are considering set1 as {a, b}. There is no ordering among elements

Comment: also we just can't assume the size of set2 to be some number. It may contain 3 elements also, but since we are taking sets. duplicates will not be repeated

Comment: I think it will be helpful if you can edit this question with some sample. That will help in understanding problem better.